# Does XPath substring work in the Firefox web inspector/console?

Tags: firefox, xpath, substring, gecko

This Xpath returns a percentage (e.g, 16%):

```
//div/div/div[@class='underlay']/strong
```

I want to extract just the digits so I tried [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring)

```
substring (//div/div/div[@class='underlay']/strong, 1, 2)
```

but it just returns an error message.

**Is this supposed to work?**

According to the documentation on the link above the syntax is `substring(string, start, length)` and it is supported by Gecko.

Are there any other way to just get the digits (16)?

Thank you.

---

Update: I used it in the web inspector's search field as well as in the console using $x("//*")

Comment: Can you literally type the XPath expression `//div/div/div[@class='underlay']/strong` in the console? Or do you use `$x('//div/div/div[@class='underlay']/strong')`? Anyway, `substring($x('//div/div/div[@class='underlay']/strong').textContent, 1, 2)` might do.

Comment: It should work. You say it returns an error message, but you don't say what the error message was, so it's hard to say what went wrong.

Comment: @ConalTuohy It just says "No matches". I use it in the web inspector search field.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion below? That worked for me, using the `document.evaluate` function. But unless you show us what your input document is, we can't tell whether your XPath is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

I just opened Firefox's inspector panel on this very page and evaluated the following in the console:

```js
document.evaluate("substring(//div[@itemprop='text']/p[1], 39, 2)", document).stringValue
```

The result was the string "16". So I think we can say that it should definitely work.